# Dialogflow Draft impacting released Actions on Google Action

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

**Initial Situation**
We have a published Google Action with Version `V1`. It has intents `A` and `B` and uses the Dialogflow ES - Google Action integration. The fulfillment URL for the intents is  `example.com/v1`. It has been reviewed and is in Production and working fine.

**New Version Expected Outcome**
We want to deploy a new version `V2`, which has an additional intent `C` and a new fulfillment url `example.com/v2`.
According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/assistant/df-asdk/versioning)

> New Action submissions create a snapshot of your Dialogflow agent at
> the time of submission. Future edits to your Dialogflow agent do not
> impact this snapshot (or version). For edits to go live, you must
> submit your draft for alpha, beta, or production release in the
> Actions Console.

In the past this also worked. We imported a new version of the dialogflow agent with a new fulfillment URL and the existing production version was not touched and we could submit a new version for alpha, beta review or production review.

**Current Problematic Behavior**
The production version `V1` is not frozen anymore but seems to be directly linked to the Dialogflow draft. As soon as we import the new action or even just change the fulfillment URL this change is reflected also in production without any review.

We've verified this both via selecting a version in the Google Actions simulator, and also by using Google Assistant on a device with another account which is neither developer nor beta tester and being able to invoke the new Intent `C` and being redirected to the new version of the backend.

One observation is that in the past the versions released through submitting a version in the Google Actions console showed up in dialogflow under published versions with a note `Version created from Actions on Google console.` However, for the last production version and subsequent alpha versions this entry is missing.

The issue is currently also being tracked in the dialogflow issue tracker here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/217720434

I am writing this here because the Google Actions support is very adamant that I should use these "community forums" for technical issues.

We are interested in finding a workaround as this currently blocks submitting a beta version with the new functionality unless we just make the new functionality also available publicly inadvertantly.